# Help determining the probability of multiple related coin flips

Tags: probability

I'm trying to figure out if my school can get a bowl game, but for simplicities sake, I'm going to use a coin flip analogy. No, this is not homework.

You have 3 lists. The first with 19 items in any order, the second with 12 items in numbered order. You also have a third list with 17 free spaces. 8 items are on both lists 1 and 2.

Start with your first list. For every item, flip a coin.

If the item is also not on list 2, do this: If it's heads that item goes into a free space on your 3rd list. Continue to the next item.

If the item is on both lists 1 and 2, do this: If it's heads, the item goes into a free space on your 3rd list and is removed from the second list. If it's tails, that item is marked with a star on your second list.

Once you're finished with list 1, proceed to list 2.

If an item is marked out, skip it. If an item has a star next to it, place it into a free space on your 3rd list. If an item is unaltered (it was not also on the first list), flip a coin. If it's heads, it goes into a free space on the list. My question is, after completing this process, what is the probability there will be at least 1 free space remaining on list 3?

Comment: NB: We don't care if something is home work or not; we just want people to show their *own* work.  Please provide some of yours so we can see just what you need help with.  Don't be afraid to show mistakes; nobody learns without getting it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

To help you get started:

> You have 3 lists. The first with 19 items in any order, the second with 12 items in numbered order. You also have a third list with 17 free spaces. 8 items are on both lists 1 and 2.
>
> My question is, after completing this process, what is the probability there will be at least 1 free space remaining on list 3?

The numbers on the list aren't important; it's how full list 3 becomes at the end.   So, rather, we can model the situation using coloured balls in boxes.   Box 1 contains 11 green and 8 red balls, box 2 contains 4 blue balls.   We are then interested in the probability that 16 or less balls are moved to box 3 if we do the following:

> Draw balls from box 1, tossing a coin, until box 1 is empty.
>
> - If its green and the toss is heads, add it to box 3.
> - If its red and the toss is heads, add it to box 3, else add it to box 2
>
> Then draw balls from box 2 as before.
>
> - If it is red, add to box 3, either way
> - If it is blue, and to box 3 on a result of heads.

So Let $X,Y,Z$ be the respective counts of green, red, and blue balls added to box 3.

- What are the probabilities that a particular ball of each colour will be added to box 3?
- What are the probability mass functions for the counts of each colour added?
  $\mathsf P(X=x), \mathsf P(Y=y), \mathsf P(Z=z)$
- What is the probability that the sum of these three counts will be 16 or less?
  $\mathsf P(X+Y+Z\leq 16)$